# Install Required Plugins Cloudify AWS Error

Tags: cloudify

I am following documentation: http://getcloudify.org/guide/3.2/getting-started-bootstrapping.html, but when running the command:

```
cfy local create-requirements -o requirements.txt -p aws-ec2-manager-blueprint.yaml
```

I get the error below:

```
Additional properties are not allowed ('data_types' was unexpected); Path to error:
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Run `cfy --version`. Then make sure that the `aws-ec2-manager-blueprint.yaml` is of a matching version (if you got it through GitHub, make sure that you downloaded it from a tag whose name is identical to the CLI version you installed).

Comment: The version of Cloudify I am using is "Cloudify CLI 3.2.1". And my blueprint, I get here: https://github.com/cloudify-cosmo/cloudify-manager-blueprints/blob/master/aws-ec2/aws-ec2-manager-blueprint.yaml. These versions are compatible?

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs due to incompatibility between the CLI version you use, and the manager blueprint you're trying to bootstrap with.

For bootstrapping, in order to ensure compatibility, you must ensure that the version of the CLI is at least as recent as the version of the manager blueprint you're bootstrapping with.

Your CLI version is 3.2.1. The manager blueprint you're using was taken from the master branch in GitHub, which currently contains 3.3 pre-release code. You can obtain the 3.2.1 version by adjusting the branch/tag in GitHub's website (switch to the 3.2.1 tag).